# how to run firstapp flutter 1.5

Tags: flutter

i tryed testdrive for flutter installed on windows as here https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/test-drive

defaut application generated work, well, but when i try to follow the snd part at 
https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/codelab

i get errors:

```
error: The function 'MyApp' isn't defined. (undefined_function at [flutter_app007] lib\main.dart:3)
error: 'MaterialApp' isn't a function. (invocation_of_non_function at [flutter_app007] lib\main.dart:8)
error: 'Scaffold' isn't a function. (invocation_of_non_function at [flutter_app007] lib\main.dart:10)
error: 'AppBar' isn't a function. (invocation_of_non_function at [flutter_app007] lib\main.dart:11)
```

for this code in main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child: const Text('Hello World'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

i checked flutter doctor, but show nothing bad.. any idea?

Comment: i tryed flutter_view, and heeloworld. all need to upgrade dependencies to work..
tryed to do the same on my project, in console/project typed: flutter upgrade, but get Upgrading Flutter from C:\Users\christian\Documents\flutter...
Updating 3ea4d0634..bc7bc9408
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
        bin/internal/update_dart_sdk.ps1
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to the project directory and open windows cmd. and try `flutter run`

Comment: using android studio, in terminal, flutter run -> 
 NoSuchMethodError: Attempted to use type 'MyApp' as a function. Since types do not define a method 'call', this is not possible. Did you intend to c
all the MyApp constructor and forget the 'new' operator?
 Receiver: MyApp
Tried calling: MyApp()
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/dart:core/object_patch.dart:46)
#1      main 
#2      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/dart:isolate/isolate_patch.dart:279)
 #3      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/dart:isolate/isolate_patch.dart:165)

Comment: stack not allowed full text response, i cuted E/flutter ( 4299): at each start line

Answer (score 0):

ok, i finally resolved the problem. 
when i was typed 'flutter_console.bat', i was get after, 'mysql is unknow program '. i finally founded that an install of MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\ setted his path in PATH env variable. this path poisonned result path integration , returning 'mysql is unknow program' and stopping project generation.. . desinstalling the mysql software solved the problem by cleaning path from his entry and now, the project can be created and work as expected..
very strange, no..?